# Spark - Hive UDF is working with Spark-SQL but not with DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I use hive UDF in spark SQL it works. as mentioned below.

```scala
val df=List(("$100", "$90", "$10")).toDF("selling_price", "market_price", "profit")
df.registerTempTable("test")
spark.sql("select default.encrypt(selling_price,'sales','','employee','id') from test").show
```

However following is not working.

```
//following is not working. not sure if you need to register a function for this 
val encDF = df.withColumn("encrypted", default.encrypt($"selling_price","sales","","employee","id"))
encDF.show
```

**Error**

```
 error: not found: value default
```

Comment: well this is a temp table in the spark domain now, not a Hive table or db, afaicrhiw.

Comment: How about using `df.withColumn("encrypted", expr("default.encrypt(selling_price,'sales','','employee','id')"))`?

Comment: @mck perfect. it's working. However, why? why it's working with expr and not working without it.

Comment: @GaurangShah see my answer for a brief explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive UDF is only available if you access it through Spark SQL. It is not available in the Scala environment, because it was not defined there. But you can still access the Hive UDF using `expr`:

```
df.withColumn("encrypted", expr("default.encrypt(selling_price,'sales','','employee','id')"))
```